# Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "Unable to connect to the remote server"

Tags: installation, windows-10, runtime-error, nativescript

I just started to install `NativeScript` on Windows 10 with this command:

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://www.nativescript.org/setup/win'))"
```

that I got from installation guide here https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/start/quick-setup

But I get this error message:

```
Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "Unable to connect to the remote server"
At line:1 char:1
+ iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://www.nativescr ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException


C:\Windows\system32>@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://www.nativescript.org/setup/win'))"
Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "Unable to connect to the remote server"
At line:1 char:1
+ iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://www.nativescr ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

What is the problem and how can I fix?

Comment: Make sure the URL https://www.nativescript.org/setup/win (which then redirects to https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NativeScript/setup-scripts/master/native-script.ps1) is accessible in your network.

Comment: @Manoj : I also faced same issue. The url you mentioned is opening in my browser, still i am facing the same error

Answer (score 2):

The following steps worked for me:

1. Download the file from the URL (https://www.nativescript.org/setup/win).
2. Run cmd as administrator and cd to the directory where you downloaded the file.
3. In cmd execute the following: `powershell -noexit "& ""./native-script.ps1"""`